# SUMPRODUCT with wildcard

Tags: excel-2010

I have the `SUMPRODUCT` working with hardcoded values however I want to use a wild card for the B clomun in my example.

Here is my data

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
| A COLUMN | B COLUMN | C COLUMN  |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| Status   | Fruit    | Quanitity |
|          |          |           |
| Fresh    | Apple    | 6         |
|          |          |           |
| Fresh    | Apricot  | 7         |
|          |          |           |
| Stale    | Apple    | 4         |
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to match `Fresh`, `AP*` and then sum the matches form Column C.

I have the following

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$840="AP*"),--($A$2:$A$840="Fresh"),$C$2:$C$840)
```

Working code with the Wildcard but the count is off

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH"AP",$B$2:$B$840,1))*($A$2:$A$840="Fresh")*($C$2:$C$840))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SUMPRODUCT()` function does not support wildcards within an array-type expression.  The same result can be achieved with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A1000="Fresh")*(LEFT(B2:B1000,2)="Ap")*(C2:C1000))
```

[image]